# Google Maps load issues on PHP page

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I'm connecting a Google Map to a MySQL database to list distributors all over the world, and I seem to be having a few issues.

1. Sometimes the page itself will not load at all in Firefox (v4 on Mac). It's temperamental on my machine (FF v3.6 Mac) and a Windows machine (FF v4 Win 7), ok in Safari/Opera, doesn't load at all in IE 9 (Win 7). Not sure if it's a network issue or code.
2. Load time is pretty slow. Might be because the map covers the whole page (will create a square block to place it in).

The URL of the page is [here](http://www.cloud.co.uk/test/dmap.php) and I used the code from [Sean Feeney's page.](http://sean-feeney.com/2011/03/php-google-maps-geocoder-tutorial.html)

The code I have is:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=<I entered my key here>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body onUnload="GUnload()">
<div id="map" style="position:absolute;top:0px;bottom:0px;left:0;right:0;"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var map;
var latlngbounds;
if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    function createMarker(point, address) {
    var marker = new GMarker(point);
    var html = address;
    GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
    });
    return marker;
    }

    function extendBounding(point) {
    latlngbounds.extend(point);
    var zoom = map.getBoundsZoomLevel(latlngbounds);
    if (zoom < 10) {
        zoom = 12;
    }
    map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter(), zoom);
    }
}

map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl3D());
map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
latlngbounds = new GLatLngBounds();

GDownloadUrl("genxml.php", function(data) {
var xml = GXml.parse(data);
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
    var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
    var marker = createMarker(point, address);
    map.addOverlay(marker);
    extendBounding(point);
}
});
}

//]]>
</script>
```

The code that gets the data is the same as the example.

Any ideas as to why it doesn't always load in the browsers, and why it seems to take a while to load?

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: Google Maps has been horribly slow as of late. The problem may not be in your code.

Comment: How much time does downloading `genxml.php` take? Open the URL my-site.com/path/to/genxml.php in your browser and note the time (using FireBug net inspector for example).

Comment: genxml.php takes about 1 second to load on average. Sometimes it's slightly more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Ideally you should wrap the code that loads the map inside a document ready or window load event.
2. I notice that your code is not nested properly inside the `GBrowserIsCompatible()` block so please fix that.
3. As far as I remember, Google maps API v2 requires you to call the [`setCenter()`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMap2.setCenter) method before doing any operations on the map. So to begin with, set the center to `(0, 0)` immediately after creating the map.
4. I notice that you're downloading XML data before you add markers to the map. You must take into account the time taken by the server to serve the XML data. If you've called the `setCenter()` before downloading the XML, the map will display while the XML downloads asynchronously.
5. Inside the code that handles the XML data: when you add a marker, do not call `setCenter()` immediately. Doing so will cause the function to be called 1000 times if you have 1000 markers in your XML. Instead, just call `latlngbounds.extend(point)`. Once you have iterated the loop, calculate the zoom/center and call `setCenter()`. This way you will end up calling this function only twice.

## Edit

I've figured out what the problem is. The genxml.php *randomly* returns the string `Google Geo error 620 occurred` which cannot be parsed as XML which raises JavaScript errors and no markers are shown. Better have a look at the code of that file and see why this happens randomly. On other times when that file actually returns valid XML, the markers appear as expected.

Comment: Thanks Salman. I've amended the code and when I added a line to setCenter (immediately below the map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl()); line) sometimes the map loads in FF with no markers, but upon refresh the map will load properly. If I refresh again, either the map will load on it's on with no data, or it will load properly!

Comment: @Adrian: The map should load after you call setCenter. I set the center after calling new GMap2 and before adding controls however I am not sure if this has something to do with the problem. The markers load sometime after genxml.php is loaded. Does firefox give you an error or something (press CTRL+SHIFT+J or use FireBug). Also try adding this line in the beginning of the function that is called by GDownloadUrl: `if(data === null) alert('genxml.php failed')`.

Comment: Not had chance to look yet (work is mega-busy). Will hopefully try as soon as I can.

Comment: Thanks for the input Salman - I've looked through the database and some of the addresses do not translate to Google. Those it can display, are. I'll ask the client to clean their data.

Answer (score 0):

It appears Google recently tightened geocoding requests. If you send 10 too fast, it cuts you off with 620 error. The solution they recommend is adding a dynamic timer. Other stackoverflow posts suggested a 0.25 second static timer was good enough, but I've found Google's recommendation of using a while loop that increments the timer value as needed works better. For example:

```
// Initialize delay in geocode speed
    public $delay = 0;
public function lookup(arguments)
        {

            $geocode_pending = true;

        while ($geocode_pending) {
            $search = //address string to search;
                    $response = $this->performRequest($search, 'xml');
                    $xml      = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
                    $status   = (int) $xml->Response->Status->code;

            switch ($status) {

            case self::G_GEO_SUCCESS:
                    require_once('placemark.php');

                    $placemarks = array();
                    foreach ($xml->Response->Placemark as $placemark)
                        $placemarks[] = Placemark::FromSimpleXml($placemark);
                $geocode_pending = false;
                    return $placemarks;

            case self::G_GEO_TOO_MANY_QUERIES:
                $delay += 100000;
            case self::G_GEO_UNKNOWN_ADDRESS:
                case self::G_GEO_UNAVAILABLE_ADDRESS:
                    return array();

                default:
                    throw new Exception(sprintf('Google Geo error %d occurred', $status));
            }
            usleep($delay);
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run your map code with `window.load` after everything is loaded:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function initAutocomplete() {
                var p_lag=$('#longitude').val();
                var p_lat=$('#latitude').val();
                if(p_lat==''){
                    var p_lat=20.593684;
                }
                if(p_lag==''){ 
                    var p_lag=78.96288000000004 ;
                }
            var myLatLng = {lat: p_lat,lng: p_lag};

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), {
                center: myLatLng,
                zoom: 5,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                draggable: true,
                map: map,
                title: 'Map'
            });

            // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
            var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
            var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
            //map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

            // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
            map.addListener('bounds_changed', function () {
                searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
            });

            //Click event for getting lat lng
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
                $('input#latitude').val(e.latLng.lat());
                $('input#longitude').val(e.latLng.lng());
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (e) {
                $('input#latitude').val(e.latLng.lat());
                $('input#longitude').val(e.latLng.lng());
            });

            var markers = [];
            // [START region_getplaces]
            // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
            // more details for that place.
            searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function () {
                var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

                if (places.length == 0) {
                    return;
                }

                // Clear out the old markers.
                /*markers.forEach(function (marker) {
                    marker.setMap(null);
                });*/
                markers = [];

                // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                places.forEach(function (place) {
                    var icon = {
                        url: place.icon,
                        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                    };

                    // Create a marker for each place.
                    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        icon: icon,
                        title: place.name,
                        position: place.geometry.location
                    }));

                    $('#latitude').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
                    $('#longitude').val(place.geometry.location.lng());

                    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);

                    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                        // Only geocodes have viewport.
                        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
                    } else {
                        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                    }
                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                });
            });
        }
        );
```